# timestamp - regex to change from one format to another

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, timestamp

I have a file: `START.txt` with lines like:

```
13.03.2013 12:13:42|STRING1|NUMBER1|NUMBER2|NUMBER3
```

and I want change all the lines from this file to the following format:

```
12:13|STRING1|NUMBER1|NUMBER2|NUMBER3
```

How can this be done?

Comment: "How can this be done?", you ask. By parsing the input, throwing away the bits you don't want, and keeping the bits you do want. Possibly with `awk`. Or `python` or `perl`. Or maybe even `sed`...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/:[0-9]+\|/,"|",$2);print $2}' file
12:13|STRING1|NUMBER1|NUMBER2|NUMBER3
```

Just delete seconds from the second part and print it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this GNU `sed` command,

```
$ sed -r 's/^[^ ]+? ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}(.*)$/\1\2/g' file
12:13|STRING1|NUMBER1|NUMBER2|NUMBER3
```

And through awk,

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{sub (/^[^ ]+? /,"",$1); sub (/:[0-9]{2}$/,"",$1);}1' file
12:13|STRING1|NUMBER1|NUMBER2|NUMBER3
```

Comment: +1 for the `sed` solution, but `+` instead of `+?` will do (aside from being unnecessary, replacing it would allow your solution to work on FreeBSD/OSX as well, if you also replace `-r` with `-E`: `sed -E 's/^[^ ]+ ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}(.*)$/\1\2/g' file`)

Comment: like this `sed 's/^[^ ]\+ \([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\):[0-9]\{2\}\(.*\)$/\1\2/g' file`

Comment: Yes, using a _basic_ regex would make it even more portable, but you're using `\+`, which is not part of the POSIX basic-regex spec (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) and fails on OSX, for instance; replace it with `\{1,\}`: `sed 's/^[^ ]\{1,\} \([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\):[0-9]\{2\}\(.*\)$/\1\2/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

Using this pattern should match each line and capture the portion that you wish to retain:

```
^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s(.*)$
```

You can see an example of the pattern in action here: http://regexr.com/38vq0

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{split($1,fld,/[.: ]/);$1=fld[4]":"fld[5]}1' file
12:13|STRING1|NUMBER1|NUMBER2|NUMBER3
```

- Set the Input and Output Field Separators to `|`.
- Split the First column on space,  `.` and `:` and put the values in an array `fld`.
- Re-construct column 1 to the desired array values
- Using `1` you print the line (which is idiomatic way of saying `{print $0}`.